# How to organize international products in database

Tags: mysql, database-design

Right now I have US products in my database only. They reside within a table named `products`.  These products are searchable through assigned tags which are in a separate table.
My challenge is to now add products from a different country with the requirement that wherever the user is from he will only see products from his country.

The country can either be selected by these infamous country-flag-picker dropdowns, set in the user profile or first determined by the visitors IP.

How would you store the international products in the database? Presumably there will not only be one more country added but many more.
Would it either make sense to simply add a column in the `products` table which country this product belongs to *or*
have a mapping table *or*
have separate tables for each country *or*
something totally different?

Right now I can not say for sure that each product will only be sold exclusively in one country. So I have to assume that one product may be sold in more than one country.

Looking forward to hear your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a classical many-to-many case.

Create a country table and a reference table which stores links between countryID and productID. That way you'll be able to sell a product in only one country or as many countries as you want.

There is a lot of information on SO about many-to-many relationships: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=many-to-many+mysql

Comment: I guess my concern was that if I go this route my `products` table will get really big. Don't know if performance will take a hit this way. But I guess this is the right way to go. And improve performance thereafter :)

Comment: If there will be overlapping business activities between products for different countries. This is the way to go. Even if it's just for admin overviews, statistics, etc. If you think that there will be almost no interaction between the products of one country and the products of another country, you may also have separate tables but then it gets trickier if you need products from several country tables.

Comment: Makes sense as I'd have duplicates otherwise. Thanks a lot Markus!

Comment: Prematurely optimizing for assumed performance hits by sacrificing proper normalization wouldn't be a good idea IMO. If later on you need to split the table, you can work with table inheritance techniques, resp. partitioning of your product table.